# xls-parser returning an empty object after parsing a non-empty file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, onchange, xlsx, form-control

I'm using [xls-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xls-parser) to parse a csv file. I'm calling the onFileSelection API of the parser in handleFileChange event of FormControl component. But, I'm getting an empty object every time as a response from this API.

Code:

```
<FormControl
  type="file"
  name="myFile"
  onChange={this.handleFileChange}
/>

'use strict'
var xlsParser = require('xls-parser');

handleFileChange(event) {
  var file = _.get(event, 'taget.files[0], null);
  var data = xlsParser.onFileSelection(file);
  console.log(data); // This data is empty
}
```

xls-parser Code:

```
'use strict';
var sheetJs = require('xlsx');
var parsedXls;

exports.onFileSelection = function(file) {
  parsedXls = [];

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  reader.addEventListener('loadend', function() {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
    console.log("Entered");

    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }

    return onLoadEvent(binary, reader);
  });

  return parsedXls;
};
```

The 'loadend' event is triggered only after handleFileChange function is completed. I want to get the file parsed within the handleFileChange function. How is the 'loadend' event being triggered here and can I get it triggered in handleFileChange function?